# How to get the incremental difference in a running total column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help me, that how to get count column here in Excel from the running sum column.

```
Country Date        Total Count Count
US      25/03/2020  1      1
US      26/03/2020  3      2
US      27/03/2020  10     7
US      28/03/2020  15     5
BG      25/03/2020  2      2
BG      26/03/2020  5      3
BG      27/03/2020  10     5
BG      28/03/2020  12     2
BG      29/03/2020  20     8
BG      30/03/2020  25     5
BG      31/03/2020  31     6
BG      1/4/2020    40     9
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, please [edit] your post and share more info like,, the formula you have tried so far and what you are expecting to count finally !!

Comment: Meanwhile you may try `=C3-C2` in cell `D3` & fill down.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your data is grouped by country and sorted by date (as in your example), you can use this simple formula:

`=C2-IF(A2=A1,C1,0)`

[image]